# How do I show the inequality $\tan(|\Re(\pi z/4)|) \le |\tan(\pi z/4 )|$ for $z$ in the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

I trying to prove the "Schwarz's lemma for harmonic functions:"

If $u:\Bbb D \to \Bbb R$ is harmonic, $u(0) = 0$, and $|u(z)| \le 1$ for each $z \in \Bbb D$, then
$$ |u(z)| \le \frac{4}{\pi}\arctan(|z|). $$

The idea I have is to notice that since $\Bbb D$ is simply connected, $u$ is the real part of an analytic function $f:\Bbb D \to \Bbb C$. In particular, we may choose its harmonic conjugate so that $f(0) = 0$.

Now since $|u(z)| \le 1$, $f(\Bbb D) \subseteq (-1,1)\times\Bbb R$, and we can map this infinite strip conformally onto $\Bbb D$ by the map $z \mapsto \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4} z\right)$.

From here, we can use the standard Schwarz lemma on the function $g:\Bbb D \to \Bbb D$ defined by
$$ g(z) = \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}f(z)\right) $$
since $g(0) = 0$. This gives
$$ |g(z)| \le |z|, $$
and unpacking this gives
$$ \left|\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}f(z)\right)\right| \le |z|. $$
In order to complete the proof, I must show the inequality
$$ \tan\left(\left|\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{\pi}{4}z\right)\right|\right) \le \left|\tan\left(\frac{\pi}{4}z\right)\right|, $$
so that I can then get
$$ \tan\left(\left|\frac{\pi}{4}u(z)\right|\right) \le |z| $$
and hence
$$ |u(z)| \le \frac{4}{\pi}\arctan(|z|). $$

I found that you can write $\tan(z)$ in terms of its real and imaginary parts as
$$ \tan(x + iy) = \frac{\sin(2x) + i\sinh(2y)}{\cos(2x) + \cosh(2y)}, $$
and using [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/itrgnp9ske) I assured myself that the inequality is true, but I have no clue how to show such an inequality.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. MathJax works in titles, too

Comment: I was wondering if it did, but I found an article recommending to not use MathJax in titles since they show up in non-formatted places as well.

Comment: If you look at the site, MathJax in Titles is ubiquitous.  You shouldn't use display mode in titles, because it sometimes gets messed up.  In this case, even when I was editing the title, I misunderstood what it said.   (I thought it was supposed to say $\frac\pi{4z}$.)  I wouldn't write math anywhere on this site, title, questions, comments, without using MathJax.

Comment: Check this: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2040276/42969.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ with $|z|\le\frac\pi4$. Then using the formula fot $\tan z$ given in the question the inequality
$$
\tan(|\operatorname{Re z}|)\le|\tan z|\tag1
$$
is equivalent to:
$$\begin{align}
&\tan^2 x(\cos2x+\cosh2y)^2\le \sin^22x+\sinh^2 2y=\cosh^22y-\cos^22x\\
&\iff\frac{\cos^22x}{\cos^2x}+2\tan^2x\cos2x\cosh2y-\cosh^22y\frac{\cos2x}{\cos^2x}\le0\\
&\iff \cos2x(\cos2x+2\sin^2x\cosh2y-\cosh^22y)\le0\\
&\iff \cos2x(\cos2x+(1-\cos2x)\cosh2y-\cosh^22y)\le0\\
&\iff \cos2x(\cos2x+\cosh2y)(1-\cosh2y)\le0\\
\end{align}$$
and the last inequality is obviously true for $-\frac\pi4\le x\le\frac\pi4$.